# Append numpy array by zeros

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of size cxl filled with random numbers. I would like to add v zeros at the end of every row (c). I am getting a weird error message which drives me crazy.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
v = 3
c = 3
l = 50
m = (np.random.rand(c, l) > 0.5) * 1
for m1 in m:
    padding = np.zeros(v, dtype=int)
    m1 = np.concatenate(m1, padding)
```

Error message:

```
  line 218, in main
    m1 = np.concatenate(m1, padding)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Both padding and m1 are ndarrays, I just don't get it why it does not work. (well in fact, it also does not do what I finally asked for, since I still need to put all m1 back together.)

Comment: this first argument of `concatenate` must be a tuple: `m1 = np.concatenate((m1, padding))`

Comment: maybe you're looking for `m = np.hstack((m, np.zeros((c,v), dtype=int)))`?

Comment: I just found one which could actually do the trick:

Comment: m = np.pad(m, ((0,0),(0,v)), 'constant')

Comment: By the way, thank you for the concatenate tuple thing. Haven't seen that

Comment: The error is caused by using `padding` as the second `axis` argument to `concatenate`.  `axis` can only be one number, or an array with only one element.

Comment: The first thing you should have checked was the `np.concatenate` docs.  Many errors are the result of giving functions the wrong arguments.